# My Junit tests can't compile using 'mvn clean install' on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, junit

My relevant pom sections are below:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have a maven projects, and I can run all unit tests successfully when I execute them in Eclipse by clicking "src/test/java" -> "run as" -> "Junit tests". However, most of the unit tests fail when I run them using "mvn clean install" at command line on my Windows 10.

Strangely, the same project I can run all unit tests with "mvn clean install" at command line on my Ubuntu machine.

What's unique to cause this issue on Windows machine with "mvn clean install"?

EDIT:
I found the source of the issue, but can't understand why?

The test failed when initializing a class by loading a text file, and it fails at this particular entry from the file:

```
♥|+|love
```

When loading the file, each line is parsed and validated by this code:

```
String[] entry = line.split("\\|");
if (entry.length != 3) {
   log.error(String.format("Invalid line: %s in %s " + line, filePath));
}
```

Then 'entry' is supposed to be made up of 3 elements: {"♥", "+", "love"}. This says the parse is right when running in Eclipse Windows or Ubuntu machine, but fails when running in command line on Windows.

Now the question is, why does it fail when parsing or asserting this condition? I suspect it is due to encoding. It might be the case that when running at a terminal on Windows, the heart symbol may run into a problem of encoding, however, in my pom.xml, I had this line:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

so I am puzzled why it happens. The good thing is that I now found out where is the problem.

Comment: Did u get any exception on windows?

Comment: Yes, the error messages says that some classes can't be initialized.

Comment: Adding stack trace to original question helps others to solve it

Comment: In your unit test you made some assumptions about the environment that are not always true.

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks.